# Image Zoom-In Zoom-Out in NSImageView

Tags: cocoa, zooming

Can anyone please suggest me a good sample code for zooming image in NSImageView.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimageview), you'll see that NSImageView doesn't support this. Use [Image Kit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartz/imagekit) instead.

Comment: The "accepted answer" does not actually answer the question of how this can be done using NSImageView, rather than e. g. IKImageView.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you want to try using [ImageKit](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartz/imagekit)'s IKImageView instead. This gives you zooming, rotation, etc...all for free.

Comment: Yeah, ImageKit is a nice idea, but my requirement is NSImageView

Comment: The only problem is that IKImageView sucks big time the moment you want to scroll or zoom with a non-idiotic anchor (read: other than bottom left). There are tons and tons of threads by people having trouble with this and trying various hacks with different (but always low) degrees of success...

Answer (score 2):

While technically NSImageView doesn't technically support this, it is possible. I believe by changing the bounds of the NSView that you're using, and make sure that the image is set to "Proportionally Down", or "Proportionally Up or Down".

This code seems to work for me, on OSX 10.9 (Mavericks)

```
   NSSize size = [_imageView bounds].size;

   NSSize newSize = NSMakeSize(size.width * 0.90, size.height * 0.90);

   [_imageView setBoundsSize: newSize];
```

I have also had success "embedding" an image view inside a scroll view, and then using magnification on the scroll view. YMMV

Answer (score 2):

You can embed your image view in an `NSScrollView`. Prepare your scroll view like this:

```
private var scrollView: NSScrollView = {
    let view = NSScrollView()
    view.allowsMagnification = true
    view.minMagnification = 1
    view.maxMagnification = 5
    return view
}()
```

and set its documentView to your image view:

```
scrollView.documentView = myImageView
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand what you mean by "zooming image" - this seems to be pretty easy. Take the view's frame and scale it at will (although adding limits is obviously highly advisable), while having the image scaling type set to `NSImageScaleProportionallyUpOrDown`:

```
NSRect newFrame = NSMakeRect(newOriginX, newOriginY, newSizeWidth, newSizeHeight);
[myNSImageView setFrame:newFrame];
```